# Converting a Tikz length into a TeX length

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am given a length specified in an arbitrary Tikz-supported format (i.e., anything that the user might assign to a key such as, e.g., `inner sep`).

I would like to convert that length into TeX dimensions (i.e., something I can assign to a TeX dimen register). The length should be interpreted like lengths in y-coordinates, in case that makes a difference.

For concreteness, say the length is stored in `\length`, and I want to put the result in `\@tempdima`.

I have tried the following hack:

```
\def\length{1pt}% Just as an example. 1cm or 1 or \dimen should also work
\pgfpointxy{0}{\length}% This computes a point at (0,\length)
\@tempdima\pgf@y% Assigns the y-coordinate of the computed point to \@tempdima
\typeout{\the\@tempdima}%
```

Interestingly, this outputs 28.45274pt, and not 1pt as expected.

What is the correct approach for getting a length in TeX coordinates.

(Background: I am drawing a bounding box around a set of nodes, similar to `fit`, and I want to support a key that specifies additional padding, similar to `inner sep`.)

**Clarification**: It should work for any length that is supported by keys like `inner sep`. So if `\length` is `3pt`, then `\@tempdima` should be 3pt. If `\length` is `1mm`, then `\@tempdima` should be `2.845274pt`. If `\length` is `10`, then `\@tempdima` should be ten times the unit for a vertical coordinate (by default, `284.5274pt`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pgfpointxy` macro uses its arguments as the factors of the unit x and y lengths (namely `\pgf@xx` and `\pgf@yy` values in the current scope). Length units are stripped off from the magnitudes for convenience by the math parser such that you don't need to strip them yourself.

So, what is happening is that `1pt` becomes 1 and gets multiplied with the value of `\pgf@yy` which is 1cm by default. And 1cm is equal to 28.45274 TeX points.

If you want the lengths to be respected then you need to use `\pgfpoint` macro.

```
\def\length{1pt}%
\pgfpoint{0pt}{\length}% Notice pt after 0 for consistency
\@tempdima\pgf@y% 
\showthe\@tempdima%
```

which gives `1.0pt`. Note that TikZ/PGF also offers scracth dimens `\pgf@x<a,b,c,d>` for quick operations.

Also you can set any TeX dimen via `\pgfmathsetlength` for arithmetic operations.

To check whether the input is a dimension expression or not you can use `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\makeatletter
\def\myfunc#1{%
    \def\mylength{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\mylength}
    \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared%
        \pgfpoint{0}{\mylength}%
    \else%
        \pgfpointxy{0}{\mylength}% This computes a point at (0,\length)
    \fi%
    \@tempdima=\pgf@y% Assigns the y-coordinate of the computed point to \@tempdima
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\myfunc{10}
\the\csname @tempdima\endcsname

\myfunc{10pt}
\the\csname @tempdima\endcsname
\end{document}
```

This gives

> `284.52744pt`
>
> `10.0pt`

Comment: As far as I can see, this will only work if `\length` contains a TeX dimension (i.e., using TeX units). (So the code could be simplified to `\@tempdima=\length\relax`.) But I want the code to *also* work if `\length` contains Tikz dimensions. I added a clarification to the question.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh Not really. TikZ already parses the input and decides what the unit argument is . Try my code and it will give you the clarification. Otherwise you have to check whether the argument is a number or a scalar.

Comment: On my system, with `\def\length{1}` I get `1.0pt`. See https://gist.github.com/dominique-unruh/b01e93adc8198c848c6bbde2637a05bc#file-test-tex for the exact input and input I used.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh If you are trying to replicate the TikZ behavior then you need to test the input via `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared` etc. Can you edit your question and put test cases and the supposed output?

Comment: Test cases can be found in the clarification. Basically, your code works for all cases except the `\def\length{10}` case. Mine works only in the `\def\length{10}` case.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh See the edit